# Form doesn't submit javascript set values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form:

```
<form id="form-new" data-target="#quote-modal">
    <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Enter a Zip Code" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search Homes" />
</form>
```

When this form gets submitted I run this code:

```
$('#form-new').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var modal = $($(this).data('target')),
        zip = $(this).find('input[name=zip]').val();

    modal.toggleClass('open');

    if(zip) {
        //Here's all the variations I tried
        // 1
        $('#zip-input').val(zip);

        // 2
        $('#zip-input').attr('value', zip);

        // 3
        document.getElementById('zip-input').value = zip;
    }
})
```

This code pops up a form that has more fields that the user fills out and auto-populates the zip code input if the user set one.

The problem is when the popup form gets submitted. All of the values in the form get submitted except for the zip code if the zip code input was populated with javascript. If I type in a value then it submits just fine.

I've tested and made sure after setting the value with `document.getElementById('zip-input').value = zip;` that the value is actually set with `console.log(document.getElementById('zip-input').value)`. The value only goes blank after the popup form is submitted.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or what's causing this. Is it a bug, or do the browsers do this on purpose? What can I do to resolve this issue, or do I need to take a different approach?

Let me know if anything is unclear and I can clarify.

EDIT: Here is the popup form html structure

```
<form id="quote-form">
    <input type="text" class="input-element" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
    <input type="text" class="input-element" placeholder="Last name" name="lname" required>
    <input type="text" class="input-element" placeholder="Address" name="address" required>
    <input id="zip-input" type="text" class="input-element" placeholder="Zip Code" name="zip" required>
    <input type="text" class="input-element" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" required>
    <input type="submit" id="next-4" class="btn submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is all it goes through before I dump the data

```
$_POST['fname'] = @trim($_POST['fname']);
$_POST['lname'] = @trim($_POST['lname']);

$_POST['phone'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_POST['phone']);
$_POST['phone'] = preg_replace('/^[01]*/', '', $_POST['phone']); //No prepending 0/1's
$_POST['phone'] = substr($_POST['phone'], 0, 10);

var_dump($_POST);
die;
```

I just recently tried this:

```
$('#quote-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).serializeArray());
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

and the zip code data was an empty string. So the value is not even being posted to the server.

Comment: "zip = $(this).find('input[name=location]').val();"
?? Setting zip = an input with name equal to location???                                     and here is your example HTML "<input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Enter a Zip Code" class="required" />"

Comment: Was a mistake I typed in so. I changed to make it more clear. I am getting and setting the value successfully in the other form currently.

Comment: I don't think you error is in this code - why are you so sure that `zip` is not included?

Comment: When I `var_dump($_POST)` in my PHP script the data gets sent to then the zip code looks like this `["zip"]=> string(0) ""`

Comment: is the modal form data submitted by the form action attribute directly, or do you have more javascript that handles the modal data?

Comment: It's submitted by the form action.

Comment: Have you tried: `modal.find('#zip-input').val(zip)`? Edit: forgot the quotes in the find() method.

Comment: Nope. I will try it real quick.

Comment: Still nothing. I noticed that when I click the submit button the value in the zip input goes blank. It has it there before I submit, but after I submit the value goes blank. All of the other input field values will stay. Then it goes on to submit the data.

Comment: Is there any other javascript that might be acting on the modal when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: No, there's not any other javascript that acts on it.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I've never seen a form drop values on submit unless something was removing them via a script.

Comment: Here's a link to a video to how it currently works. https://drive.google.com/open?id=15WXtPAX3QTFGQatQkJLdeTFWh5FhGlWd

Comment: can you share the submit code of 2nd form?

Comment: I'll edit the post with it.

Comment: I have to imagine whatever's causing your issue is not included here - perhaps a bit of JavaScript or something elsewhere. I've copy+pasted your code to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrt3qh0x/2/) and the issue is not replicated.

Comment: Hmm... well thanks for attempting. I guess I'll have to keep looking elsewhere.

Comment: I think I found the issue. The developer before me added jquery placholder. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>` Apparently that was resetting the field to the placeholder text before it was submitted. I don't know why it only affected javascript set inputs.